# Android runtime - does ART miss optimization opportunities over Dalvik?

Tags: android, optimization, compiler, jit

Is ART a strict improvement over Dalvik, or there are optimizations that an ahead-of-time compiler will miss compared to JIT, but Google decide they don't matter in practice?

For example, with JIT, you can dynamically detect a hot loop and perform aggressive inlining, which in turns allowing many other optimizations. Such inlining, however, can blow up space if performed globally ahead of time without profiling.

Is it the case that there are optimizations that Dalvik performs that ART gives up?

Comment: Dalvik didn't do such hotspot optimizations either, as far as I know. Code was compiled once, at application startup, before the runtime would have had the chance to gather any profiling data about which loops are and aren't hot.

Comment: Hotspot optimizations, continuous compilation and so on are cheap (actually free) when there is so much computing power and RAM that the typical mix of apps is incapable of utilizing it all and the compiler can just grab the rest, but mobile devices aren't quite there yet. The Azul JCA has 864 cores and 768 GB of RAM, and even after careful fine-tuning most Java apps are incapable of utilizing more than a couple hundred of them. So, even if the compiler and the GC each use 50 cores (the typical maximum under even the most extreme loads), that still leaves over a hundred cores idle.

Comment: Note that Android spans a *huge* array of devices, much more so than iOS, for example. With the introduction of the Apple Watch, iOS has expanded its reach a bit, but Android runs on anything from Smart Watches and Wearables to cheap, small phones to flagship phones with 8(?) cores to tablets of all sizes and form factors to set-top boxes and media stations to convertibles, laptops, [even full-featured desktop PCs](http://www.zdnet.com/article/hp-takes-android-pcs-commercial/)! So, the argument that "mobile devices get more powerful" doesn't hold: everytime our mobiles reach desktop …

Comment: … performance, someone introduces a new category of mobile devices that is even smaller and more resource-constrained and starts anew with the performance specs of a phone from 5 years ago. At some point in the future, it might make sense to use different runtimes for resource-constrained and more powerful devices.